# JavaScript how to set nested json object data into single nested map

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, dictionary, protractor

I want to set nested json data into nested map and iterate it.Consider the below sample json as example, i want to set firstName, lastName, address object, address 1 object value into single nested map.Also how to iterate it to get value from address object city field value.

Kindly provide the better solution.
Sample json:

```
 [{
    "firstName": "Jihad",
    "lastName": "Saladin",
    "address": {
      "street": "12 Beaver Court",
      "city": "Snowmass",
      "state": "CO",
      "zip": "81615"
    },
    "address1": {
      "street": "16 Vail Rd",
      "city": "Vail",
      "state": "CO",
      "zip": "81657"
    }
  }]
```

Comment: Please don't remove the formatting from the question. You can select the code, click Ctrl+k and the editor will auto format tt for you (FYI For next time)

Comment: If you ask a "better solution" then you need to have a solution somewhere to compare to. Normally you should always try at least something your self.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine all the addresses, you can do the following

```
const people = [{
  "firstName": "Jihad",
  "lastName": "Saladin",
  "address": {
    "street": "12 Beaver Court",
    "city": "Snowmass",
    "state": "CO",
    "zip": "81615"
  },
  "address1": {
    "street": "16 Vail Rd",
    "city": "Vail",
    "state": "CO",
    "zip": "81657"
  }
}]
const newPeople = people.map(person => {
  const addresses = [person.address]
  for (let i = 1; person['address' + i]; i++) {
    addresses.push(person['address' + i])
  }
  return {
    firstName: person.firstName,
    lastName: person.lastName,
    addresses
  }
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(newPeople))
/*
[{
  "firstName": "Jihad",
  "lastName": "Saladin",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "street": "12 Beaver Court",
      "city": "Snowmass",
      "state": "CO",
      "zip": "81615"
    },
    {
      "street": "16 Vail Rd",
      "city": "Vail",
      "state": "CO",
      "zip": "81657"
    }
  ]
}]
*/
```